# Azure WCF Service + Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox Visual Web Part = error

Tags: sharepoint

I have problem to call Azure WCF Service from sandbox Visual Web Part Sharepoint 2010. All installed al local computer Windows 7 64 Ultimate - 
Sharepoint Foundation 2010 to develop web parts and Visual Studio 2010 with Azure SDK. Web Service starting in local Azure Emulator, web part in local computer.
When i use standart master "Add Service Reference" to web part, that generate app.config, then throw error:

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client serv = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
 Label1.Text = serv.GetData(9);
```

*Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.*

When i create connection programmatically -

```
 EndpointAddress adr = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:81/Service1.svc"));
 BasicHttpBinding basic = new BasicHttpBinding();
 ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IService1Channel> fact = new ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IService1Channel>(basic, adr);
 Label1.Text = fact.CreateChannel().GetData(8);
```

throw error:

*Request for the permission of type "System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".*

app.config webpart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:81/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

web.config Azure WCF Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <!--  To collect diagnostic traces, uncomment the section below or merge with existing system.diagnostics section.
        To persist the traces to storage, update the DiagnosticsConnectionString setting with your storage credentials.
        To avoid performance degradation, remember to disable tracing on production deployments.
  <system.diagnostics>     
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources> 
   </system.diagnostics> -->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

P.S. When all moved to work deployment - Azure и Sharepoint Online - errors again. I create connection programmatically, because read, that in sandbox
solutions app.config not deployed with web part, we must duplicate his code in web.config Sharepoint 2010 - but in Sharepoint Online this file is closed from developers!

Answer (score 0):

I have verified first that you sure can use SharePoint Designer 2010 to create an external content type that consumes and writes data to SQL Server, a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Service or a .NET type.

Next SharePoint BCS supports both SOAP and OData however WCF Data Services supports  OData services, so to  consume a WCF Data Service, you need OData base connectivity. Data view web parts can issue GET requests which works for OData feeds.

SharePoint Online Office 365 supports sandbox solutions which means .Net/C# code and solution deployed web parts are possible however I am not sure if connecting SP Web Parts is possible in the way that you describe because sandbox solutions don't support making outbound web calls.

Have you verified the last part?

Answer (score 0):

You receive correct error from the SharePoint
*Request for the permission of type "System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".*
This is because Sandbox restrictions. You can see all permissions which are denied to the sandbox code from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454%28v=office.14%29.aspx) MSDN article.  And WebPermission along with SocketPermission  which are dinied for code in sandbox solution.

If you want to access external services, does not matter using the TCP or HTTP protocol you should move to the full trust solutions.